# Anystock comparisonMode same value in tooltip

Tags: tooltip, stock, anychart

When using a stock chart, I am using the `comparisonMode` with a date. The value displayed by the crosshair is correct, but the value in the tooltip is the real value (not compared). How could I display the compared value instead?

[image: sample]

As you can see on the picture, the compared value is `107.1` but the tooltip is displaying the actual value `893.5`. I am using anychart `8.0.0`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm glad to inform you that in the new version of AnyStock 8.1.0 the calculated change value is available right from the point information. It may be used in tooltips and legends. I guess this is exactly what you were looking for.
The example of using this feature you may find [on this link](https://playground.anychart.com/EktD1Ajl).
Now the context of every point includes valueChange and valuePercentChange properties.

Comment: Hi Anychart team, great library. Just wanted to know before purchasing whether anychart supports showing excel sheet online? Since, this is unrelated to this page, you can ping me over [here](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17/javascript) at anytime. Thanks.

Comment: @Mr_Green thank you for your interest in AnyChart! Our library supports loading data from Google Spreadsheet to the chart and export to .xlsx file which could be downloaded. But, unfortunately, the library doesn't provide showing excel sheet online. You may learn more about these features in the following articles: https://docs.anychart.com/Working_with_Data/Data_Adapter/Loading_Google_Spreadsheet and https://docs.anychart.com/Common_Settings/Exports#excel

Answer (score 1):

This feature requires a few additional lines of JS code, I prepared an example below to show how it works. Now compared value is shown in cross-hair label, in the tooltip, and in legend.

```js
anychart.onDocumentReady(function() {
    var dataTable = anychart.data.table();
    dataTable.addData(get_dji_daily_short_data());

    var firstMapping = dataTable.mapAs({'value': 1});
    var secondMapping = dataTable.mapAs({'value': 3});

    chart = anychart.stock();


    var plot = chart.plot();
    var series0 = plot.line(firstMapping);
    var series1 = plot.line(secondMapping);

    var yScale = plot.yScale();

    // Set comparison mode.
    yScale.comparisonMode("value");

    var xScale = chart.xScale();

    chart.container("container");
    chart.draw();

    //reference points of both series
    var firstVisibleValue0 = null;
    var firstVisibleValue1 = null;

    //after chart rendering format tooltip and legend
    getVisibleValues();
    tooltipLegendFormat(firstVisibleValue0, firstVisibleValue1);

    //after every scroll change recalculate reference points
    //and reformat tooltip and legend
    chart.scroller().listen('scrollerchange', function() {
        getVisibleValues();
        tooltipLegendFormat(firstVisibleValue0, firstVisibleValue1);
    });

    function getVisibleValues() {
        // Gets scale minimum.
        var minimum = xScale.getMinimum();
        //select data from mappings
        var selectable0 = firstMapping.createSelectable();
        var selectable1 = secondMapping.createSelectable();
        // Sets value for search.
        var select0 = selectable0.search(minimum, "nearest");
        var select1 = selectable1.search(minimum, "nearest");
        // get values in first visible points
        firstVisibleValue0 = select0.get('value');
        firstVisibleValue1 = select1.get('value');
    }

    function tooltipLegendFormat(firstVisibleValue0, firstVisibleValue1) {
        //format tooltips and legends of both series
        series0.tooltip().format(function () {
            return  'Series 0: ' + Math.round(this.value - firstVisibleValue0);
        });
        series0.legendItem().format(function(){
            return  'Series 0: ' + Math.round(this.value - firstVisibleValue0);
        });
        series1.tooltip().format(function () {
            return  'Series 1: ' + Math.round(this.value - firstVisibleValue1);
        });
        series1.legendItem().format(function(){
            return  'Series 1: ' + Math.round(this.value - firstVisibleValue1);
        });
    }

});
```

```css
 html, body, #container {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.anychart.com/releases/8.0.1/js/anychart-base.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.anychart.com/releases/8.0.1/js/anychart-stock.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.anychart.com/releases/8.0.1/js/anychart-exports.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.anychart.com/releases/8.0.1/js/anychart-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.anychart.com/csv-data/dji-daily-short.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.anychart.com/releases/8.0.1/css/anychart-ui.min.css" />
    
    <div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: Ok I see how this would work, but since you are already displaying the compared value on the crosshair position, couldn't you also just have this value available by default in the tooltip? you must be compiling it already, and if I write this code I will basically do it again, which is not very efficient